# Cannot use Powershell to set a remote application pool properties

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have script which can successfully create application pool and set properties in IIS. And I use following code to set it remotely.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $strSvr -ScriptBlock $script
```

And code in script are like:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$appPool = New-Item $apppoolname        
$appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value $iisAppPoolDotNetVersion
$appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "enable32BitAppOnWin64" -Value "true" 

$appPool.processModel.username = $domainusername        
$appPool.processModel.password = $domainuserpassword        
$appPool.processModel.identityType = 3
$appPool | set-item
```

The problem is: the code to set identity is working, but code to set .Net version and enable32bitapplication failed. The same code works on local machine.

Any idea?

P.S. I am using PS3.0

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Does your user have write access to the target configuration file or files?

Comment: Do you receive any errors when executing remotely?

Comment: Where does this value `$iisAppPoolDotNetVersion` come from?  If it is external to the script you show above it needs to be passed in via the Invoke-Command's `-ArgumentList` parameter.

Comment: Hi All, (1) I assume I have right to write to target machine as I use domain admin account and I can set 'Identity' of app-pool with no problems. (2) I didn't receive any exception in the case that I use try {} catch {} block;  (3) $iisAppPoolDotNetVersion is just a variable which equal to 'v4.0'. It's passed in by argumentlist

Comment: BTW guys, have you ever applied the same code to see whether can set .net version & enable32bit on a remote server's app-pool?

Answer (score 2):

Code that works for me:

```
  Import-Module "WebAdministration"
  $pool = New-WebAppPool -Name $poolname -Force

  $pool.processModel.username = $domainusername
  $pool.processModel.password = $domainuserpassword
  $pool.processModel.identityType = 3
  $pool | Set-Item 

  Set-ItemProperty ("IIS:\AppPools\$poolname") -Name managedRuntimeVersion -Value "v4.0"
  Set-ItemProperty ("IIS:\AppPools\$poolname") -Name managedPipelineMode -Value 0

  Start-WebAppPool -Name $poolname
```